# Potted Salix has only produced leaves at the end of the stems so far this year

Tags: growth

[image]I was given a potted salix last year and it grew well. So far this year, only the ends of the stems have leaves (probably about 25% of the length of the stems). There are nubs along the stems where I would expect the rest of the growth to appear, but no sign of anything further.
I topped up with compost a couple of weeks ago. Am I being impatient, or do I need to do something else to encourage more growth. The leaves that have appeared look healthy and green.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add a photo which also shows the pot the plant is in as well as the plant -for ID - you don't say which Salix variety it is.  I'm assuming its outdoors?